# Book about kid going to Mars and communicating with his friend

Tags: story-identification, novel, mars

A few years ago, I read a book that was about this kid going to Mars with his father and communicating with his friend. It also describes what it would feel like to leave the atmosphere in a rocket, and his friend talks about some secret or coverup and tells his friend to get off the network or something. It also mentions hoverboards and a hover board park?

Answer (score 6):

Might it be..

Hover by Mark Wayne McGinnis

https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/57820997-hover

> The year is 2049, and we most certainly are not alone… A miraculous, life-enhancing microbe has been discovered on Mars and the race is on to bring the organism back to Earth. But failed physicist Jack Harding has his own reasons to get to Mars first—to save a dying, seven-year-old boy. All he must do to succeed is break the law—the law of gravity. To make the mission to Mars, Jack must perfect a ground-breaking anti-gravity technology and avoid being killed by the ruthless billionaire, Travis Locke, a man who has no qualms with breaking a few laws himself—even murder. The life of a young boy, one of five orphans entrusted to Jack’s care, hangs in the balance as Jack struggles between the man he once was and the man he hopes he can be again